Rstudio are too slow through Firefox foxyproxy
I have 2 server with rstudio.
rstudio on Server 1 can be successfully accessed by Firefox foxyproxy all the time.
rstudio on Server2 ran normally by Firefox foxyproxy until last week, then the rstudio webpage became extremely slow and consuming too much memory on my computer (not server2). My group member can use rstudio on Server2 normally these days.
I even do not know how to troubleshoot this weird problem.
I wish your help very much!
